# Android service stopped but bluetoothChatService continues

Tags: android, android-intent, service, bluetooth

I have implemented the [Android BluetoothChatService](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com.example.android.bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.html) in a service, but haven't found a way to stop it when I want to stop the service.
The service is started with an intent:

```
intent = new Intent(mContext, service1.class);
```

and stopped with

```
stopService(intent)
```

which reports the service is stopped, **but the bluetooth continues** - the handler in the service continues to receive callbacks from the BluetoothChatService and respond to them. So although the service is stopped, the handler within it remains alive.
BluetoothChatService contains the following code, which looks like it should stop the threads:

```
public  void stop() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }
        if (mAcceptThread != null) {
            mAcceptThread.cancel();
            mAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }
```

I don't understand this.

Comment: `cancel()` is not a method of `Thread`.  What are those things actually?

Comment: it is defined in the bluetoothChatService.java file  as: private class ConnectThread extends Thread { which in turn  does a socket.close(). Check the reference.

Comment: A person would have to be really bored (or really need the rep) to dig through so much code to try to find your answer for you.  I suggest reducing the problem to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  You will very likely find your answer in the process, and if you don't, you'll be much more likely to get help.